# How to use WebSockets in AWS EB Flask App with either Flask-SocketIO or Amazon API Gateway

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a backend server running on AWS that has been up and running for a while, but as I'm trying to add a chat feature, I'm confused as to how to make it work with my current app architecture. What I'm trying to achieve with the chat feature is that some of my users are students and some are teachers. When a student sends a message, I want it to be broadcasted to all teachers and when a teacher replies, it should be broadcasted to that same student only.

My app architecture :

- A flask app running on elastic beanstalk that I set up following (using the Python platform) : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html
- A postgresql database running on RDS
- I acquired a domain through Route 53 and I serve the traffic to my flask app over HTTPS
- I use the default application load balancer that is created when creating an env in elastic beanstalk, meaning there can be multiple instances
- Here is the content of my Procfile that serves the app :

```
web: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --workers=4 --threads=5 application
```

All the similar questions I could find on here remained partially or not answered :

- [flask-socketio run on Application Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459764/flask-socketio-run-on-application-load-balancer)
- [Socket Io in AWS ElasticBeanStalk Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584103/socket-io-in-aws-elasticbeanstalk-node)
- [Using Socket.IO with HTTPS and AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050613/using-socket-io-with-https-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk)
- [Deploy flask-socketio on beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756046/deploy-flask-socketio-on-beanstalk)

To add the chat feature that I'm trying to implement that will allow users on my client to send chat to each other as soon as they open the app, I have tried implementing those two options :

1. Using Flask-SocketIO : as I'm using Flask, this seems like the most natural solution. My problem is I can't simply wrap my app as in the [documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) and start the web server with `socketio.run(app)` as in :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   socketio.run(app)
```

since on elastic beanstalk, the server is served with gunicorn as defined in the Procfile. I found

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 application:application
```

but this only works with one worker and in my case (4 workers, 5 threads) is the optimal setup to run my flask app, how can I handle this in my context ? Should I instead have 2 gunicorn processes, one for the normal flask API and one for the websocket dedicated to the chat feature ? I'm also trying not to spin up a new instance just to host the chat feature since that would generate more costs.

2. Using Amazon API Gateway to build a Websocket API that my clients interact with when using the chat feature. This Websocket API interactions would then have to be relayed to my flask app, for instance to store the chats in my RDS database. Considering my use case described above :

> When a student sends a message, I want it to be broadcasted to all teachers and when a teacher replies, it should be broadcasted to that same student only.

Is that kind of use case achievable with Amazon API Gateway without having to add any external library to my Flask app and simply replying to HTTP requests made from the Gateway ?